# MATLAB: How can I avoid iamresize and VideoReader if they are taking too much time?

Tags: matlab, mean-shift

I am doing mean shift color based image segmentation on video frames.
Here is my code:

```
 while hasFrame(v)
   if k == 1
       s(k).cdata = readFrame(v);
       a = s(k).cdata;
       I = imresize(a,[50,50]); 
       [means, Ims, Nms] = Ms(I,bw); %Mean Shift on first frame
       Ims = im2uint8(Ims);
       s(k).cdata = Ims;
   else
       s(k).cdata = readFrame(v);
       a = s(k).cdata;
       I = imresize(a,[50,50]);
       [Ims,data2cluster]= MeanShiftCluster2(I,means); % simple segmentation based on norm using means of first frame              
       Ims = im2uint8(Ims);
       Ims = imresize(Ims,[500,720]);
       s(k).cdata = Ims;
   end

   k=k+1;
 end
```

I am sending first frame for mean shift implementation and then using same resulting means for all other frames to calculate their respective clusters on basis of euclidean distance (My frames have minor changes).

Problems:
Profiler tells that iamresize and VideoReader functions are taking too long to execute. Are there any substitute that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

`imresize` may be the slowest step of your processing.
But here are several idea to fasten the process.

`imresize` do what is called interpolation. This is can be a slow process, but the speed depends on the quality you want for the output. The default in matlab is `bicubic`. You can try `bilinear` or `nearest`. *e.g* :

```
[...] = imresize(...,'nearest');
```

In my personnal experimentation, I have also found that imresize as equivalent functions have some overhead. You could probably go "much" faster by calling the function only once for all your video frames. You will need to have enough memory to do this. Suppose that you you have all your frames in a 3d matrix `dataMovie`. When constructing this matrix, preallocation (by getting the number of frame) will help gaining some speed !

```
k = 0.5; % scaling parameter
tform = affine2d([k 0 0;0 k 0;0 0 1]);
dataTform = imwarp(dataMovie,tform,'nearest');
```

And then, apply your processing to the resize movie frame by frame. You can also provide the type of interpolation `nearset`, `linear` or `bicubic`.

If you are working on a color movie, you need to stack the 3 color layers of all the frame together, and get them back using the proper indexing.